# python - numpy: read csv into numpy with proper value type

Tags: python, numpy, types

Here is my test_data.csv:

```
A,1,2,3,4,5
B,6,7,8,9,10
C,11,12,13,14,15
A,16,17,18,19,20
```

---

And I am reading it to a numpy array using the code below:

```
def readCSVToNumpyArray(dataset):
    with open(dataset) as f:
        values = [i for i in csv.reader(f)]

    data = numpy.array(values)

    return data
```

---

In the main code, I have:

```
    numpyArray = readCSVToNumpyArray('test_data.csv')
    print(numpyArray)
```

which gives me the output:

```
(array([['A', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
       ['B', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'],
       ['C', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15'],
       ['A', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20']], 
      dtype='|S2'))
```

But all the numbers in the array is treated as `string`, is there a good way to make them stored as `float` without going through each element and assign the type?

Thanks!

Comment: `numpy.ndarrays` are homogeneous. That's part of why they have improved performance. Maybe you could have two separate arrays, one for numbers and one for strings? Or a list of strings and array of numbers? Otherwise, you need to look into [numpy records](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.core.records.fromfile.html) or some other datastructure. Have you considered pandas dataframes?

Comment: Take a look at [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-read-csv-table), it is really good at loading csv. You may convert pandas table (`DataFrame` actually) to numpy array easily just by `asarray(table)`.

Comment: If you don't want to involve an extra package (pandas), note that `np.fromfile` or `np.genfromtxt` are also good utils for reading text file, in your case you have to define a data type and pass it to these functions. Go and see their docstring and also take a look at `np.dtype`.

Comment: What kind of array do you want?  In particular how should the string and integer values be combined?  All elements of an array must be of the same type (though the dtype may be complex, see `structured arrays`).

Comment: @hpaulj : I need them to be String and Number for different columns. So I can use DictVectorizer to transform the categorical variables later.

Comment: I'd recommend `loadtxt` over `fromfile`.  `genfromtxt` is the most commonly used numpy csv reader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the first character at each line is a string you'll have to use a more flexible type in numpy called "object". Try with this function and see if this is what you are looking for:

```
    def readCSVToNumpyArray(dataset):
        values = [[]]
        with open(dataset) as f:
            counter = 0
            for i in csv.reader(f):
                for j in i:
                    try:
                        values[counter].append(float(j))
                    except ValueError:
                        values[counter].append(j)
                counter = counter + 1
                values.append([])

        data = numpy.array(values[:-1],dtype='object')

        return data

    numpyArray = readCSVToNumpyArray('test_data.csv')
    print(numpyArray)
```

The results are:

```
    [['A' 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0]
     ['B' 6.0 7.0 8.0 9.0 10.0]
     ['C' 11.0 12.0 13.0 14.0 15.0]
     ['A' 16.0 17.0 18.0 19.0 20.0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd read it in using Pandas which lets you set dtype per column very easily.

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 

pdDF = pd.read_csv(
    'test_data.csv', 
    header=None, 
    names=list('abcdef'), 
    dtype=dict(zip(list('abcdef'),[str]+[float]*5)))
```

now each column will have the appropriate dtype.

```
pdDF.b
Out[24]: 
0     1
1     6
2    11
3    16
Name: b, dtype: float64
```

If you still want it in numpy arrays, you can just take values.

```
npArr = pdDF.values

npArr
Out[27]: 
array([['A', 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0],
       ['B', 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0],
       ['C', 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0],
       ['A', 16.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0, 20.0]], dtype=object)
```

It's still going to be objects for the 'row' arrays, because you can't make 'A' into a float, but the individual values will be floats as desired.

```
type(npArr[0,1])
Out[28]: float
```

Finally if you want just an array of floats, that's also easy enough...  just spit out all but the first column as an array and it will have dtype: float instead of object.

```
pdDF.loc[:,pdDF.columns>='b'].values
Out[28]: 
array([[  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.],
       [  6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  10.],
       [ 11.,  12.,  13.,  14.,  15.],
       [ 16.,  17.,  18.,  19.,  20.]])

pdDF.loc[:,pdDF.columns>='b'].values.dtype
Out[29]: dtype('float64')
```

Answer (score 0):

`np.genfromtxt` can easily load your data into a structured array.  It will be a 1d array, with a field for each column:

Simulate the file with a list of lines:

```
   In [265]: txt=b"""A,1,2,3,4,5
       .....: B,6,7,8,9,10
       .....: C,11,12,13,14,15
       .....: A,16,17,18,19,20"""
    In [266]: txt=txt.splitlines()
    In [267]: A=np.genfromtxt(txt,delimiter=',',names=None,dtype=None)
    In [268]: A
    Out[268]: 
    array([(b'A', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (b'B', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10),
           (b'C', 11, 12, 13, 14, 15), (b'A', 16, 17, 18, 19, 20)], 
          dtype=[('f0', 'S1'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4'), ('f3', '<i4'), ('f4', '<i4'), ('f5', '<i4')])
```

It deduced the `dtype` from the column values - strings and ints.  Fields are accessed by name

```
In [269]: A['f0']
Out[269]: 
array([b'A', b'B', b'C', b'A'], 
      dtype='|S1')
In [270]: A['f1']
Out[270]: array([ 1,  6, 11, 16])
```

I could also define a `dtype` that would put the strings in one field, and all the other values in another field.

```
In [271]: A=np.genfromtxt(txt,delimiter=',',names=None,dtype='S2,(5)int')
In [272]: A
Out[272]: 
array([(b'A', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), (b'B', [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]),
       (b'C', [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]), (b'A', [16, 17, 18, 19, 20])], 
      dtype=[('f0', 'S2'), ('f1', '<i4', (5,))])
In [273]: A['f1']
Out[273]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19, 20]])
```